# Difference in Line of code while publishing the test report after build in TFS to QA SONARQUBE server and PROD SONARQUBE Server

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

We are using Visual Studio Build step in TFS.

In the build steps we are using Sonarqube Scanner for build - Begin Analysis, and to publish report we are using the step Sonarqube Scanner for build - End Analysis.

By creating the service end point we will be connecting to the Sonarqube Dashboard.

We have two build definitions for PROD and QA, we are using the same source code both of them.

Once the Sonarqube begin and end analysis is done we will be comparing QA and PROD results. Now we are able to see 20k lines of code in QA Sonarqube project dashboard and 250k Lines of code in PROD Sonarqube project dashboard.

Comment: When you talk about QA SonarQube dashboard and PROD SonarQube dashboard are you talking about 2 different instances of SonarQube or 2 projects on the same server?

Comment: @Joe You may have different configurations between the two instances. Just check the build definition settings, build and other related parameters etc.

Comment: Yes they are two different instances @ Amaury Levé

Comment: Everything is same in the build definitions... we are just changing the Sonarqube URL for QA and PROD

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone pls help me out

Comment: Could you share the entire build logs for the two build definitions with "system.debug" variable set to "true"?